# Working on fixing wp-front-end-editor, encountering undefined index

Tags: plugins, php, front-end, editor

Scribu's [Frond-End Editor plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/front-end-editor/) is brilliant, but throws some Strict errors in debug mode.

Since I'm using the plugin on a project, I figured I'd fix the errors. (You can see my changes from the original [on my Github](https://github.com/bigsweater/wp-front-end-editor)).

I managed to fix the strict errors (they were all about methods not matching their parents), but my changes resulted in the following error:

`Notice: Undefined index: after_widget in \wp-content\front-end-editor\php\fields\widget.php on line 25`

and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

You're welcome to peruse the code on Github, but I'll reproduce the offending method below:

```php
function wrap( $content, $data = null, $params = null ) {
    if ( !$this->check() )
        return $params;

    $p =& $params[0];

    // Text widgets are handled differently
    if ( 0 === strpos( $p['widget_id'], 'text-' ) )
        return $params;

    $wrap = parent::wrap( '', '', array( 'widget_id' => $p['widget_id'], 'sidebar_id' => $p['id'] ) );

    list( $before, $after ) = scbUtil::split_at( '</', $wrap );

    $p['before_widget'] = $p['before_widget'] . $before;
    $p['after_widget'] = $after . $p['after_widget'];

    return $params;
}
```

The thing that confuses me about this is that doing a `var_dump` on `$p` shows that the `'after_widget'` index *is* defined. Also, commenting out *either* of the `$p[]` declarations results in the error disappearing.

Hopefully we can get this resolved and submit the pull request. (Feel free to download and test my changes from Github, too; I haven't done too much testing yet.)

Comment: try to use it with `isset()`

Comment: @sisir - No dice, using a conditional like that results in no widgets showing up at all. I'm not sure why I can't just make `$p['after_widget'] = $after`, but it doesn't work.